# Pulkovo Transformation parameters in QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, parameters

I'd like to use a 7-Parameter transformation between Pulkovo Geodetic CRS ([EPSG 4178](http://epsg.io/4178)) and ETRS89 Geodetic CRS ([EPSG 4258](http://epsg.io/4258)) in QGIS.

There are different sets of transformation parameters for this task. I'd like to use Pulkovo to ETRS89 method with [EPSG 1775](http://epsg.io/1775) with the parameters `24.9, -126.4, -93.2, -0.063, -0.247, -0.041, 1.01`.

QGIS offers exactly this parameters in the parameters-attribute in the srs.db in table `tbl_srs` (`auth_id` from 2397 to 2398).

But when I want to choose the transformation for displaying my data, QGIS offers me parameters for example for the method with EPSG-Code 1675 (see `tbl_datum_transform` in `srs.db`). It is an older method and the parameters offer less accuracy. QGIS does not offer the 1775-method here. It is not listed in the table `tbl_datum_transform`.

Why are the 1775-parameters in the `tbl_srs` table to define Pulkovo, but not as a method in the `tbl_datum_transform` table? Should I simply add it?
And when is QGIS using which transformation parameters (from which table)?
I guess I am not aware of the use of the `srs.db` in QGIS.